# Why do I get "An internal error occurred (eid 8410529)" when I try to Create An App on Yahoo Weather API?

Tags: api, yahoo-weather-api

Yahoo weather API at https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#get-started has a link under 'Get your API Keys' there is a button named 'Creat an App' that points to https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/.

Both in Chrome and IE11 when I click on it I get "An internal error occurred (eid 3030034)."

Yahoo forum requests that user us SO with tag #yahoo-weather-api

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like Yahoo has a problem inside there server code. This is an error when you view there site?

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Seems to be a problem at Yahoo's service. Guess we'll have to just wait until it's fixed.